# RegisterProperty cache display name

Tags: asp.net, .net, csla

I'm using the RegisterProperty from CSLA. I also have DisplayAttribute and DisplayNameAttribute on my properties attached to a resource. I notice that the .Name property of each of my RegisterProperty are cached. If I switch language, the .Name is not refreshed. This causes trouble since I'm using StringLengthAttribute and others to handle some business rules.

Is there a way to refresh the .Name or make sure the value isn't cached?

Comment: Yes, this might be a case where CSLA is over-optimized for performance and should re-evaluate the attribute each time instead.

Comment: https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/issues/344

Comment: @RockfordLhotka thanks for that, the custom attribute did do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I decided to create my own attribute that takes the display name as parameter. I which there was a way to disable caching.

```
Public Class StringLengthExAttribute
    Inherits StringLengthAttribute

    Private _displayResourceName As String = ""

    Public Sub New(ByVal maximumLength As Integer)
        MyBase.New(maximumLength)

        Me.ErrorMessageResourceName = "ruleExceedMaxCharacter"
        Me.ErrorMessageResourceType = GetType(My.Resources)

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal displayResourceName As String, ByVal maximumLength As Integer)
        MyBase.New(maximumLength)

        _displayResourceName = displayResourceName

        Me.ErrorMessageResourceName = "ruleExceedMaxCharacter"
        Me.ErrorMessageResourceType = GetType(My.Resources)

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function FormatErrorMessage(name As String) As String

        If _displayResourceName <> "" Then
            name = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(_displayResourceName)
        End If

        Return MyBase.FormatErrorMessage(name)
    End Function

End Class
```